# knockout : update array of the array in javascript from getJSON

Tags: knockout.js, getjson

here is my code:

```
var Feed = function (searchTerm, feeditems)
    {
        this.ID = 1;
        this.SearchTerm = searchTerm;
        this.FeedItems = ko.observableArray(feeditems);
    };

    var FeedItem = function(userName, message)
    {
        this.UserName = userName;
        this.Message = message;
    };

    var viewModel = {
        Feeds: ko.observableArray()
    };

    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);



    function getFeedData()
    {
        var url = "/Feed/GetFeedData";
        $.getJSON(url, function (data)
        {
            $.each(data, function ()
            {
                viewModel.Feeds[0].FeedItems.unshift(new FeedItem(this.UserName, this.Message));
            });
        });

        window.setInterval("getFeedData()", TIMEDELAY);
    }
```

I can't figure out how to update the FeedItems of the first Array element of Feeds. 
basically: viewModel.Feeds[0].FeedItems.unshift does not work... :(

when i just checking viewModel.Feeds, it gives me all the methods, but with viewModel.Feeds[0] it says it is undefined.

so, how to update the observable array of the first element of the observable array?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To begin with viewModel.Feeds is an empty array. So Feeds[0] will be undefined. Make sure you initialize it. 
If you cannot, then consider creating a new object and pushing into the array, if array length is 0.